# String reverse function doesn't work

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to create a function that reverses a `char *`.  This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *reverse(char *x) {
     int len = strlen(x);
     char ans[len+1];
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          ans[i] = x[len-i-1];
     }
     ans[i] = '\0';
     return ans;
}

int main() {
     char *a = reverse("hello");
     printf("%s\n", a);
}
```

It should print `olleh`, but for me, nothing prints out.  Does anyone know where I messed up?

Comment: You should avoid reversing strings.  Also [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) exists (you have a C++ tag on your question, after all), don't implement this yourself.

Comment: As this code does (should) not compile in C++, I removed the tag.

Comment: Use `std::string`. And try with "now step live" or a phrase like this ;)

Comment: returning the stack address(return ans;) will cause the undefined behavior. Change this (  char ans[len+1];) to global or heap memory and then try.

Comment: If you want to preserve the original string then you must allocate new memory in the heap and return a pointer,I would just reverse the string pointed to buy 'x'(reverse in place using a temp variable) without creating  'ans'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning `ans`, which is a pointer to an array of chars that reside in the stack when `reverse()` is called.

After `reverse()` returns, its stack frame is popped.  Thus, the contents at the memory address stored in `ans` is not well defined when you try to print it out.

To remedy this, you can use heap memory instead by using `malloc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *reverse(char *x) {
     int len = strlen(x);
     char *ans = malloc((len+1)*sizeof(char));
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          ans[i] = x[len-i-1];
     }
     ans[i] = '\0';
     return ans;
}

int main() {
     char *a = reverse("hello");
     printf("%s\n", a);
     free(a);
}
```

In this case when `reverse()` returns, `ans` will continue to point to the char array in the heap.  Just remember to free the array once you are done with it with `free()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 char ans[len+1];
```

The content of above char array will no longer available after return from the function.Memory of above array is on stack. Try by allocating memory dynamically using `malloc/calloc`.

ex:

```
 char *ans = malloc(len+1); //Note: Sizeof char is always 1.
```

Comment: I.e. by returning a pointer to it, and then dereferencing that pointer, one invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to accomplish but on unix systems, your code example should work. It is a bad idea though since you have returned memory from the stack which basically is not your memory to use and is volatile.  Often you can immediately copy the return value to local memory already allocated. If you can, I'd suggest also you pass in the destination where you want the answer or simply return allocated memory.

Comment: *on unix systems, your code example should work* - Unfortunately, [it doesn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bd9aa2f3838362e). Platform is not anywhere close to the only thing that influences the behaviour of undefined programs.